# What time format is this? (not UNIX, not UTC, nothing)

Tags: mysql, time, formatting, unix-timestamp, time-format

I'm importing data from another system to MySQL, its a CSV file. The "Date" field however contains cryptic of 3-digit time entries, here's a random sample set:

```
> 540
> 780
> 620
> 965
```

What's this? obviously its not 5:40 and 6:20. But it's not UNIX either (I tried 1225295**XXX** before I realized the time range this represents is about 16 minutes)

Anyone recognize these?

**Update**: I just noticed that further down in the replies, a coworker who's closer to the data just [opened a new SO account and added some more data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247373/what-time-format-is-this-not-unix-not-utc-nothing#247456). It seems like these numeric entries are just time entries (not date). Still clueless.

IMHO, if no one can recognise this, then it probably isn't some (if obscure) standard time format and is more likely that these entries are foreign keys.

**Update 2**: Many thanks to all! [we found the answer visually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247373/what-time-format-is-this-not-unix-not-utc-nothing#248123), but as usual, [SO pulled through clutch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247373/what-time-format-is-this-not-unix-not-utc-nothing#248070).

Comment: What dates do those numbers represent?

Comment: ... not entirely sure, all we have is a data file dump. I thought this was some obscure time format, but other than swatch time or foreign keys (to a nonexistant table)... were stumped

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the number of minutes since midnight in five minute intervals. Your range of values should be 0 to 1440

Answer (score 7):

[swatch internet time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swatch_Internet_Time)

day is divided into 1,000 equal parts.  very metric altogether.

Comment: I thought about this, but surely no-one in the world actually uses it? Besides it has no date information :-/

Comment: don't misunderestimate other people

Comment: Haven't heard about Swatch Internet Time in a while!

Comment: The stupid in that "Swatch internet time" concept is slightly burning. Can you make it go away?

Comment: "Swatch Internet Time" is just decimalized time, as originally redefined by the French Revolutionaries, with marketing. It has some advantages to the Babylonian system - tell me quickly, if a car goes at constant 30km/hr, how much distance will it go in 10 seconds? 5 minutes? 1 day?

Comment: @Joe: I wish I could +1 a comment! ;)

Comment: @joe, yes they loved the base 60 between the two rivers in iraq but you surely inferred from my answer that metric = decimalised = decimalized, you enquote it as if it wasn't.  but then again i don't get your joke so maybe i'm the eegit ;)

Comment: @dove: strictly speaking Babylonian system for time is now "metric" for it's an integral part of the international metric system :( Base 60 second is the "s" in cgs.

Comment: Just for the sake of completing my promotion for decimalized time, 30km/hr = 72km/deciday. The car would travel 720m per milliday/beat (decimal minute), 72cm per decimal second. And 720km per day :D

Answer (score 2):

I've seen some systems where the date is stored in a special table and elsewhere as an id to it. This might be one of them

Comment: Good thought, but slightly suspicious they all end in 0 or 5... it is a tiny sample though...

Comment: A system that stores dates in a different table, might very well have ids ending only in 0 or 5, in case they slipped a date... ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd be best off asking the original authors...

Alternatively, can you insert a date into the old system and export it?
If you can do that then you should be able to reverse-engineer it very easily.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution... thanks....

hmoya

9:00:00 AM  540
9:15:00 AM  555
9:30:00 AM  570
9:45:00 AM  585
10:00:00 AM 600
10:15:00 AM 615
10:30:00 AM 630
10:45:00 AM 645
11:00:00 AM 660
11:15:00 AM 675
11:30:00 AM 690
11:45:00 AM 705
12:00:00 PM 720
12:15:00 PM 735
12:30:00 PM 750
12:45:00 PM 765
1:00:00 PM  780
1:15:00 PM  795
1:30:00 PM  810
1:45:00 PM  825
2:00:00 PM  840
2:15:00 PM  855
2:30:00 PM  870
2:45:00 PM  885
3:00:00 PM  900
3:15:00 PM  915
3:30:00 PM  930
3:45:00 PM  945
4:00:00 PM  960
4:15:00 PM  975
4:30:00 PM  990
4:45:00 PM  1005
5:00:00 PM  1020
5:15:00 PM  1035
5:30:00 PM  1050
5:45:00 PM  1065
6:00:00 PM  1080
6:15:00 PM  1095
6:30:00 PM  1110
6:45:00 PM  1125
7:00:00 PM  1140

Comment: If I may ask, what algorithm is used to generate these values?

Comment: It's just the number of minutes since midnight: h * 60 + m

(or (h+12) * 60 + m, for PM times).

Answer (score 0):

Are they are supposed to represent dates or times?  If dates, then they are probably just an offset from a 'well known' epoch (like time_t are seconds from 1-Jan-70).

If you don't have documentation to find the epoch you'll need an example to work it out from.

Answer (score 0):

This represent time, no date. And the same code-time appear in different date.

Comment: Some times you can see 10/10/2005 880. The first part represent the date and the second one, must represent the time in this day.

Answer (score 0):

could be a julian date...?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to know for sure. I could be [beats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swatch_Internet_Time), but then again, it might not be.

Comment: If only there was +1 funny rating!